# SCSS - Check variable for font-family

Tags: css, sass

I need to check if my `$primary_font_family` variable contains a specific font-family.

**My question is, is this the correct method of checking the font-family inside the variable?** I am curious if the single quotes etc would cause issues.

Even when `$primary_font_family` is empty it's currently still returning a red background. My scss compiler is not returning any error, but as I know during my test, the variable was empty and it still compiled with the red background.

Code and conditional:

```
$primary_font_family: 'Whitney-Bold', sans-serif;

@if ($primary_font_family == 'Whitney-Bold', sans-serif) {
  .primary-header__brand-wrap {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

Tests:

As you can see, the second `$primary_font_family` check looks for a value `Whitney-Example` which doesn't even exist, yet it still compiles.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can surround the fonts on [`@if`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if) with `(` and `)`:

```
$primary_font_family: 'Whitney-Bold', sans-serif;

@if ($primary_font_family == ('Whitney-Bold', sans-serif)) {
  .primary-header__brand-wrap {
     background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ow5cLsxy/7/

---

**You can also look for different variables whether one of these is matching the specified value:**

```
$a: 'Whitney-Bold', sans-serif;
$b: 'Whitney-Bold', sans-serif;
$c: 'Whitney-Example', sans-serif;

//a or b or c = specified value
@if (index(($a, $b, $c), ('Whitney-Bold', sans-serif)) != null) {
  .test {
    color: red;
  }
}
```